# getElementById() returns Null for existing objects

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Near the bottom of a page that draws a data-driven grid, the grid package has this code ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, document, undefined) {
      "use strict";
      var gridColSortTypes = 
          ["string", "string", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number"],
          gridColAlign = [];
      var onColumnSort = function( newIndexOrder, columnIndex, lastColumnIndex ) {
        var doc = document;
        var offset = (this.options.allowSelections && this.options.showSelectionColumn)?1:0;
        if( columnIndex !== lastColumnIndex ) {
          if( lastColumnIndex > -1 ) {
            doc.getElementById("stockHdr" + (lastColumnIndex-offset)).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "";
          }
          doc.getElementById("stockHdr" + (columnIndex-offset)).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#f7f7f7";
        }
      };
      ...
})(this, this.document);
```

Investigating why the specified sort column colour change fails to happen, I found that although the object queried by getElementById() exists and is functioning in the page, inside this function these getElementById() calls return Null. Indeed all getElementById() calls made from this function return Null.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure the DOM elements exist and are accessible by the time this code is being executed? Try wrapping your function in window.onload. Also (unrelated and pedantic), why not just call your outer closure parameter `doc` instead of creating another var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the DOM content is not ready/accessible when you are trying to access it, try wrapping your code in `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  (function(window, doc, undefined) {
      "use strict";
      var gridColSortTypes = 
          ["string", "string", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number", "number"],
          gridColAlign = [];
      var onColumnSort = function( newIndexOrder, columnIndex, lastColumnIndex ) {
        var offset = (this.options.allowSelections && this.options.showSelectionColumn)?1:0;
        if( columnIndex !== lastColumnIndex ) {
          if( lastColumnIndex > -1 ) {
            doc.getElementById("stockHdr" + (lastColumnIndex-offset)).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "";
          }
          doc.getElementById("stockHdr" + (columnIndex-offset)).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#f7f7f7";
        }
      };
      ...
   })(this, this.document);
};
```